# Undefined reference to a defined function

Tags: c++

So presumably I am doing something incredibly stupid and just catch it, but I keep getting an undefined reference to a function that I have most definitely defined. In one of my .cpp files, I use the following command:

```
#include "MVec.h"
...
MVec ans;
...
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    ans[i] = ...
```

In MVec.h, I have:

```
class MVec {
...
inline double & operator[](const int i);
inline const double & operator[](const int i) const;
...
};
```

Finally, in mvec.cpp, I have:

```
inline double & MVec::operator[](const int i) {
        #ifdef CHECK_BOUNDS
        if(i < 0 || i >= 3)
                throw("Subscript out of bounds");
        #endif

        return vec[i];
}

inline const double & MVec::operator[](const int i) const {
        #ifdef CHECK_BOUNDS
        if(i < 0 || i >= 3)
                throw("Subscript out of bounds");
        #endif

        return vec[i];
}
```

Somehow, however, when I compile the two .cpp files and try to link them

```
g++ atommanager.cpp -o atommanager.o
g++ mvec.cpp -o mvec.o
g++ atommanager.o mvec.o -o gpumd
```

I always get an error:

```
atommanager.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `MVec::operator[](int)'
```

Here, atommanager.cpp is the name of the first .cpp file I mentioned.

Comment: Try removing inline.  When you declare it as inline, the compiler may optimize the function away, so that it no longer exists at link time.  Alternatively, include the full function definition in Mvec.h, rather than in Mvec.cpp

Comment: Removing inline does indeed solve the problem... Defining the function in MVec.h causes another compiler error (both mvec.cpp and atommanager.cpp includes MVec.h, so I get a function defined twice error). Unfortunately, I use this function a fair bit and would like to keep it inline... I'll have to try and find a way around that.

Comment: If you end up with a duplicate definition if you move the `inline` function into the header, you probably need include guards for your headers!

Comment: I have include guards, I copied the definition of the function into the header and didn't make it inline... It works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a function `inline` doesn't provide an externally visible definition: The definition is only visible within the translation where the `inline` function is defined (and I think only for calls after the `inline` definition unless the function is also declared `inline`). The easiest fix to the problem is to remove the `inline`s. Alternatively, you need to define the function in the header.